# sentry throw error on laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, sentry

I have use `Laravel 5.1` with `"jenssegers/raven": "^1.4"`

When I run `composer self-update` on server then found error `page isn’t working`

Error log is:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given' in /var/www/html/www.something.com/vendor/sentry/sentry/lib/Raven/SanitizeDataProcessor.php:54
```

Kindly help me, how to resolve this issue. I appreciate all response.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using an unofficial version of Sentry's old raven client.

You should upgrade to the latest [Sentry Laravel client](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/php/integrations/laravel/), as we're moving off raven. If you continue to have problems, email us!